# Update nuget package

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, nuget, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget-package

Good evening,

Recently I started to use .Net Core. One of the things I am trying is an API with external controllers referenced as a dll. I found that RC2 dont allow you to reference directly .dll so I created my own nuget package, deployed on build using:

```
"scripts": {
 "postcompile": [
  "dotnet pack --no-build",
  "C:\\Builds\\nuget.exe push \"%project:Directory%\\bin\\%compile:Configuration%\\%project:Name%.%project:Version%.nupkg\" -source C:\\Builds\\Packages"
 ]
}
```

Then on my API solution, I referenced my local folder as a nuget source, and included my local nuget package to the solution. It works perfectly but when I do a change on my external controllers package and rebuild, it update the .nupkg file (or create it if I remove it from the folder) correctly, then I restore the packages on my API solution, but for some reason it keeps loading the old version. I even removed the package, and added it again but keeps using the old code. I found that the only way to make it works, is to change the package version from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1, rebuild, and change the version on the api project.json. So my question is.. what I have to do to overwrite a local nuget package version when I build the changes so just restoring packages (or auto) it get the changes?

Comment: I found that the culprit seems to be C:\Users\<user>\.nuget\packages\My_Package for some reason this seems not to update on Restore Packages. If I delete the folder and then restore the packages it works. This means I have to delete this folder on the package build?

Comment: The package is being cached in the local NuGet cache. If you bump the version number, it'll bypass the cache. If you change the API library often, it might make more sense to put them in the same solution instead.

Comment: Is there a way to call cmd commands from project.json scripts? My Idea was to delete the nuget package folder *global-packages* (see `nuget locals all -list`) on the postcompile and then on precompile of the solution/libraries that use the package `restore packages`, but I cant make *rd* or *del* to work, how can I delete a folder and subfolder from project.json scripts?

Comment: You could do it with a gulp script. I think it's still better to use the version number or put them in the same solution, though.

Comment: well, I am looking for a temporary solution since they are moving to MSBuild so I hope referencing libraries become more easier and allow non-nuget references.